# Opening files through the Unity shortcuts page tries to open with Vinagre instead of Nautilus

Tags: unity

I click on the upper left corner icon, select "find files", choose any folder and it attempts to open the folder with Vinagre instead of Nautilus. I have asked this question on other forums, with no responses.

Answer (score 1):

Please look at this files and folders:

```
/usr/share/applications/defaults.list 
/usr/share/applications/mimeinfo.cache
~/.local/share/applications/  
~/.gnome/share/apps/
```

Search for "vinagre" and for "Nautilus" inside theses files and make sure you have the right associations.